# asm/socket.h: No such file or directory cross compiling Dart for Raspberry pi

Tags: dart, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspbian

I'm cross-compiling the Dart runtime using the instruction [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/RaspberryPi).

I've installed all the dependencies as specified. I've also cloned the git repository with the necessary tool chain.

I'm running the runtime compilation with this command:

```
./tools/build.py -m release -a arm --toolchain=../tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf runtime
```

The compilation starts with no problem then it stops with this error:

```
  LINK(target) out/ReleaseXARM/libdart_dependency_helper.target
  CXX(host) out/ReleaseXARM/obj.host/libdart_lib_withcore/runtime/vm/bootstrap.o
In file included from /usr/include/sys/socket.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/in.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:22,
                 from runtime/platform/globals.h:56,
                 from runtime/platform/assert.h:16,
                 from runtime/vm/allocation.h:8,
                 from runtime/vm/bootstrap.h:9,
                 from runtime/vm/bootstrap.cc:5:
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:345:24: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/socket.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
  CXX(host) out/ReleaseXARM/obj.host/libdart_lib_withcore/gen/async_gen.o
In file included from /usr/include/sys/socket.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/in.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:22,
                 from runtime/platform/globals.h:56,
                 from runtime/platform/assert.h:16,
                 from runtime/vm/allocation.h:8,
                 from runtime/vm/bootstrap.h:9,
                 from out/ReleaseXARM/obj/gen/async_gen.cc:5:
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:345:24: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/socket.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
runtime/libdart_lib_withcore.host.mk:978: recipe for target 'out/ReleaseXARM/obj.host/libdart_lib_withcore/runtime/vm/bootstrap.o' failed
make: *** [out/ReleaseXARM/obj.host/libdart_lib_withcore/runtime/vm/bootstrap.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
runtime/libdart_lib_withcore.host.mk:986: recipe for target 'out/ReleaseXARM/obj.host/libdart_lib_withcore/gen/async_gen.o' failed
make: *** [out/ReleaseXARM/obj.host/libdart_lib_withcore/gen/async_gen.o] Error 1
BUILD FAILED
```

Am I missing any dependency or package?

Comment: Did you tried this? https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/01/msg00111.html

Comment: Yes, but the apt will try to remove other packages: The following packages will be REMOVED:
  g++-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-4.9-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf
  g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf
  gcc-4.9-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
  gobjc++-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf gobjc++-4.9-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf
  gobjc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf gobjc-4.9-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Comment: I wonder if it is a problem that you use gcc 4.9 and not 4.6 as mentioned. Maybe things have changed in between? You can also try to ask on the dart:misc mailing list.

Comment: The dependecies have been installed through the suggested script. I will try to downgrade to 4.6 and also to ask in the mailing list. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I hit the same problem.  On my ubuntu 14.04 system /usr/include/asm didn't exist.  It was called asm-generic instead.  I sym-linked it and the build was able to continue.

```
cd /usr/include
sudo ln -s asm-generic/ asm
```

The build was able to continue after that.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably because you're trying to build an application without some of the include paths correctly set, for example using a 32-bit gcc on a 64-bit platform.
To resolve:

> sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this happens, but sometimes `/usr/include/asm` gets deleted. My teammates who looked at their Ubuntu x86-64 workstations found that the asm symlink was:

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 May 22  2013 /usr/include/asm -> x86_64-linux-gnu/asm
```

And the command to recreate it is:

```
$ cd /usr/include
$ sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/asm asm
```

The files in `/usr/include/asm-generic` are sometimes, but not always, equivalent to the files in the x86-64 specific directory; so it's difficult to recommend symlinking it as a workaround.

Comment: correct. In my ubuntu version, gcc-multilib will conflict with gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi.